# how to send a txt file from server to client using http in java

Tags: file, http, grails, internet-explorer-8, filestream

I have a problem in my grails application which reads a txt file stored in the disk and then sends the file to the client.

Now I am achieving this by reading the file line by line and storing them in a String array.

After reading all lines from the file, the String array is sent to the client as JSON.

In my gsp's javascript I get that array and display the array contents in a text area as

`textarea.value = arr.join("\n\n");`

This operation happens recursively for every 1 minute which is achieved using ajax.

My problem is, the txt which the server is reading consists of about 10,000 to 20,000 lines.

So reading all those 10,000+ lines and sending them as array creates problem in my IE8 which gets hung-up and finally crashes.

Is there any other easy way of sending the whole file through **http** and displaying it in browser?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

On Googling I found that, file input/output streaming is a better way to display the file contents in a browser but I couldn't find an example on how to do it.

Can anyone share some example on how to do it?

Comment: A possible solution is to check in the server if the file was modified before sending the new version. You need to refresh to show new lines append or the hole file can be modified? Another solution is to just present a message to the user, saying that the file was modified and he needs to trigger a refresh in the page to see the new content.

Comment: Thanks @SérgioMichels for your kind reply. As you said I have already implemented the appending of only the new lines. But even then my IE8 is hanging-up and the culprit I suspect is the array that contains the txt file's data.

Comment: Maybe is your `arr.join()` that's killing IE. Have you tried to send all the content of the file instead of the array of lines?

Comment: @SérgioMichels As you said I have displayed all array contents in browser. But still the IE acts in the same way it did before. No change in its behaviour.

Comment: Ok, so maybe you need to split this call. Create something like "get me line xxx to yyy" and having the total of lines, loop and make more than one ajax call.

Comment: @SérgioMichels As you mentioned I changed the code as to read only the new lines that were getting appended to the file. Now there is a slight improvement in the performance of IE but still it is crashing.

Comment: Can you update your javascript code in the question?